# How do I issue a SQL query using pyodbc that involves python variables as the parameters?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pyodbc

I am writing a program that searches a database and inputs the data into a excel file based on user selection from two calendars (on the GUI). I have a start and end date, I am passing those variables as parameters into a function for my SQL query.

How do I format the SQL query to select the values from the given dates?

Here is my code so far,

```
def load_database(startDate, endDate):

    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
    'Server=DESKTOP-KVR7GNJ\SQLBULKROLL;' 
    'Database=db_MasterRoll;'
    'UID=sa;'
    'PWD=Z28@6420d')

    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    ws.title = "Star Ledger"
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT ID, BarCode, DateTm, EntryDoor FROM dbo.tab_Rolls WHERE (DateTm >= @startDate) AND (DateTm <= @endDate)')
```

a button invokes this code by running the function "call_db_code()":

```
def call_db_code():
    firstDate = start_dateCalendar.selection_get()
    print(firstDate)

    finalDate = end_dateCalendar.selection_get()
    print(finalDate)
    load_database(firstDate, finalDate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `?` as placeholders in the query, and provide a tuple of values to substitute for them.

```
cursor.execute('SELECT ID, BarCode, DateTm, EntryDoor FROM dbo.tab_Rolls WHERE (DateTm >= ?) AND (DateTm <= ?)', (startDate, endDate))
```

See the examples in the `cursor.execute()` [documentation](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#executesql-parameters).